# Why I am getting can not resolve symbol 'R'?

Tags: android, android-activity, autolayout

Why I am getting cannot resolve symbol 'R'..??.
When I'm creating new activity on that.Class file I'm getting this problem why I don't know after creation of class I did nothing. (in that R.layout.dashboard). ("R in red color").

```
public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
     }
 }
```

please help me.

Comment: please go to file and select invalid caches and restart it will restart your android studio and problem will be solved

Comment: if problem is not solved yet, this means there must be some naming error at your xml file or you have import some image file which is not in appropriate name format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue before, can solve it by doing

```
Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

Some times you need to restart android studio and reset the cache.

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
Build -> Clean Project
```

and then

```
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

This does not require you to restart your Android Studio.